# Detecting if a variable hasn't been modified in XX seconds

Tags: java, variables, timer

Hi I've been looking at any ways if Java can detect if a variable has been modified, is this possible? I want to use a timer so that when variable is modified it will reset back to zero and start up again. If the variable goes unmodified for say 20 seconds (i.e. timer reaches 20 seconds) it will do something like print the variable.

Modified refers to any new value assignments such as `array[2] = 3`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you need to wrap the field in get and set methods, and make it `private`. Then you need to make a timestamp that gets updated with each `set` call:

```
public void setArray(int index, int value) {
    array[index] = value;
    lastModifiedTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
```

You would then need to monitor `lastModifiedTime` within a separate thread and trigger an event if `System.currentTimeMillis() - lastModifiedTime > 20000`.

Comment: This works, assuming that OP cares about `array` being modified, and not a specific index. But it's the right idea. +1.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously there is nothing built-in, you don't want to implicitly store some timestamp next to each and every variable in Java. What you can do is wrap your variable in some object, encapsulate modifications and start timer every time mutation occurs.

```
public class ListeningRef<T> {

    private final ScheduledExecutorService timersPool;

    private T value;
    private ScheduledFuture<?> timer;

    public ListeningRef(ScheduledExecutorService timersPool, T value) {
        this.timersPool = timersPool;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public T get() {
        return value;
    }

    public void set(final T value) {
        this.value = value;
        scheduleTimer();
    }

    private void scheduleTimer() {
        if (timer != null) {
            timer.cancel(true);
        }
        timer = timersPool.schedule(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("Not modified in 20 seconds: " + ListeningRef.this.value);
            }
        }, 20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
}
```

This is how you use it:

```
final ScheduledExecutorService pool = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(10);
final ListeningRef<String> listeningRef = new ListeningRef<String>(pool, "Hi!");
TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(19);
System.out.println(listeningRef.get());
listeningRef.set("Bye!");
TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(21);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap the properties in order to create a timed reset. You can base the implementation on the [PropertyChangeSupport](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyChangeSupport.html).